# React: getting undefined when accessing array in state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

when I `console.log(this.state.animal_names)` out my state element I get

> `>(2) [Array(2), Array(2)]`

When I expand that, I get

```
0: (2) ["dogNames", Array(53)]
1: (2) ["catNames", Array(100)]
```

However when I try and access those, like so:

```
desiredAnimal = "dogNames";
this.state.animal_names[desiredAnimal];
```

I get:

> undefined

how do I access these so I can loop through the arrays in each category?

Comment: if your state is an object, you can access it like that, but it is an array.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `Array` to `Object` using `Object.fromEntries`

```
const an = Object.fromEntries(this.state.animal_names);
desiredAnimal = "dogNames";
an[desiredAnimal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your array to object using `reduce()`.

```js
const animal_names = [ ["dog", [1,2,3,4]], ["cat", [1,2,3]]];

const res = animal_names.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const name = cur[0];
  acc[name] = cur[1];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res.dog);
console.log(res.cat);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your state structured like this? This might be better.

```
animalNames: {
dogNames: [],
catNames:[]
}
```

It may be easier to access all dog names if you stored all dog names as a value of your dogNames property in an animalNames object.

Comment: I am saving these names from database. the database is returning json `{"dogames": [{},{},{}], "catNames": [{},{},{}]}` - how would I best get them to save in the above format? I can edit my answer with proper code if it helps show you how I am saving them ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will fix your issue

```js
    const result = 
    [
      ["dogNames", Array(2)],
      ["catNames", Array(2)]
    ].find(item => item.indexOf("dogNames") >= 0);
    
    
    console.log(result)
```